# How does this macro work in this instance?

Tags: c

I am reading a book on linux programming, and in a header file for error handling, they show this block of code with a macro that stops 'gcc -Wall' from complaining control reaches end of non-void function. I don't completely understand how it works.

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
/* macro stops 'gcc -Wall' complaining that 'control reaches
   end of non void function' if we use following functs to
   terminate main() or some other non-void funct */
#define NORETURN __attribute__ ((__noreturn__))
#else
#define NORETURN
#endif

void errExit(const char *format, ...) NORETURN;
void err_exit(const char *format, ...) NORETURN;
void errExitEN(int errnum, const char *format, ...) NORETURN;
...
#endif
```

I would like to know exactly what it is doing, and how. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Just curious what this error is given for - is it because you have main returning an int but you don't actually explicitly return a value?

Comment: I guess. I'm not exactly sure myself... I think you may be right, because in the  comments it says 'if we use following functions to terminate main() or some other non-void function'... But how does that return a value?

Comment: As a side note, the recent C standard C11 has that functionality with a new keyword `_Noreturn`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `gcc`, the line

```
void errExit(const char *format, ...) NORETURN;
```

is translated to

```
void errExit(const char *format, ...) __attribute__ ((__noreturn__));
```

by the preprocessor. What does the `__noreturn__` attribute to do?

> A few standard library functions, such as `abort` and `exit`, cannot return. GCC knows this automatically. Some programs define their own functions that never return. You can declare them noreturn to tell the compiler this fact.

You can read more about `__noreturn__` and other function attributes supported by `gcc` at http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html.

When use a different compiler, the same line is translated to:

```
void errExit(const char *format, ...);
```